# Clone/Copy a task from MS Planner via Power Automate w/ original creator

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-planner

### Background

In our setup, Planner behaves the following:

- You create a task assigned to 4 people
- As soon as one of the assignees checks it, it's gone for all.

That's a valid use case. However we also have the use case to create one task for each person for the same topic with same content.

### What I did

In order to automate this and avoid having to tediously click and clone several times, I created a Power Automate flow that

- checks if the subject starts with "EACH: ", and if yes
- For the first assignee it simply removes the EACH:
- for all others it creates a copy of the task using

  - Get a Task
  - Create a Task
  - Remove assignees from Task (the original one)

### Problem

This works fine, although it has one drawback:
The individual assignees will be informed, that **I** assigned a task to them (since I wrote the flow), not the original task creator from our team.

Since I don't see a way in the "Create a Task" action to set the creator, is there a way to really clone a task in a better way so that they are informed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the actor cannot be specified, it will be automatically populated based on the calling token. We're working on couple of ways to directly support the scenario of similar tasks needing to be done by multiple people, but we don't have clear timelines for when these will be available yet.

Comment: Thanks Tarkan. Do you have a support request for this I could plus1?

Comment: Sure, you can add/upvote feature requests at: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/a1a93b69-2f1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472